# TypeError: uuidv4 is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this TypeError in my [code](https://github.com/umaralam48/listtracker/blob/master/src/Lists.js) can someone plz help me there seems to be an issue in line 22 to 25. This code is related to printing a todo list. In this section of [code](https://github.com/umaralam48/listtracker/blob/master/src/Lists.js) I assign the name to lists. Also on visual studio code the files are compiling without any errors whereas when I start npm this error shows up in the browser.

'''

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import List from './List.js';
const uuidv4 = require('uuid');

class Lists extends Component {

  render() {
    // If there are no lists, display a relevant message
    if(this.props.lists.length === 0) {
      return (
        <div id="listsDiv" className="List">
          <h2>Add new lists to get started!</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }

    // Otherwise, for each list, create a div
    var items = this.props.items;
    var lists = this.props.lists;
    var addItem = this.props.addItem;
    return (
      <div key={uuidv4()}>
      {lists.map(function(listName) {
        return (
          <List name={listName} items={items[listName]} addItem={addItem.bind(this)} key={uuidv4()} />
        )
      })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Lists;
```

'''

Comment: read the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Comment: I think its a valid question. If you know the answer, then discuss the answer and link to the documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to import `v4` as `uuidv4`:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
```

or

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
```

Comment: as per the [documenation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Comment: I made the point for the OP :p documentation is easy to find especially for modules installed using NPM :[

Comment: Lmao tried the documentation before posting here but the error was in another file as well because I was using uuid there as well but I thought it's just in this one. Thanks anyways @Viet

Answer (score 1):

uuid has different options to generate id's like v1, v3, v4, etc.
As you want to generate a v4 id. You can use it this way.

```
<div key={uuidv4.v4()}></div>
```

**Note:** I suggest you to import it as.It will be easy to understand.

```
const uuid = require('uuid')
```

Comment: const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
uuidv4();
This worked for me...

Comment: Yeah, that works as well. In the import method i mentioned you can generate all types of id's as it comes with all the different methods.

Comment: Yes thanks I read the documentation before posting here but this wasn't the issue I just forgot that uuid has been used in other files as well whereas I was just looking at this one.